# Not able to add a blank space in the email attachment

Tags: email-template, attachment, visualforce-template

I am trying to attach an ics file and I'm just not able to add a blank space between certain characters. I tried using `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` to even break the line but instead it's printing as it is.

Here's my code

```
<messaging:attachment filename="invite.ics">
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID::-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP;TZID=IST:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(relatedTo.Demo_Start_Date__c),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
UID:<apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.id}"/>
DTSTART;TZID=IST:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(relatedTo.Demo_Start_Date__c),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
DTEND;TZID=IST:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(relatedTo.Demo_End_Date__c),':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
SUMMARY: <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Name}"/>
LOCATION: <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Address__c}"/>BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION: Report Due Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Report_Due_Date__c}"/>
TRIGGER:-PT1D
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR 
</messaging:attachment>
```

You can see in the description that I have tried to add space between 'Report Due Date' and its value.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DESCRIPTION: <apex:outputText value="{!'Report Due Date: ' & relatedTo.Report_Due_Date__c}"/>
```

I changed my description to this and it worked!